# CSS / XPATH Selector Query

Tags: javascript, css, dom, xpath, css-selectors

A little question to our world of CSS & Xpath Selector
I've successfully obtained a text value with XPATH but I can't succeed with a CSS Selector,

Here is my example:

```
<span class="piggy">
    <i class="fa fa-try"></i>
    <strong>euros (€) !</strong>
270,38K</span>
```

I can get value "270,38K" without problem with XPATH,

```
document.evaluate('//*[@id="wrap"]/span/text()', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.textContent.trim();
```

Res -> 270,38K (**good**)

But i can't achieve it with a CSS Selector,

```
document.querySelector('span.piggy').innerText.trim();
```

Res -> euros (€) ! 270,38K (**wrong**)

Do you have a clue to only get text value of span (without children content) with a css selector?

Thank you all !

Comment: Good one I too would have wondered the same. Btw did you try this in firefox as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector is fine you just have to do a little extra work by getting the text node that contains the wanted text as those cant be obtained by css selector

Get the [last child node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/lastChild) (which should be a text node) of the element by using lastNode and get the textContent of that

```
document.querySelector('span.piggy').lastNode.textContent
```

or use the [childNodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) list

```
let nodes = document.querySelector('span.piggy').childNodes;
console.log( nodes[nodes.length-1].textContent );
```